# Best way to mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this on my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ category.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ article.php?url=$1
```

The article page is ok, showing like this:

```
http://www.example.com/article-name
```

But the category page I would like to change from:

```
http://www.example.com/category/category-name
```

To:

```
http://www.example.com/category-name
```

In my pages, I send the url with this:

```
<a href='/category/". $art_url"'></a>
```

The problem is when I change the string inside of the .htaccess to the same of the article, category shows ok but the article page comes with no content.

Please, how can I achieve what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to change your URLs to `/article-name` and add a rewrite rule to change them to `article.php?url=$1`. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @deceze. I have changed the .htaccess to RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ category.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ article.php?url=$1. Also changed the url to <a href='/". $art_url"'></a>. The problem is that when I click in category it shows ok, but inside of category when I click in the article it does not show anything